# synced force sell based on product quantity in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to force sell based on the product quantity if the customer adds 5 product 1 accessories should add. if they add more then 5, 2 accessories should add.
so the accessories should add in the multiple of five.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'prefix_add_additional_product', 10, 6 );
/**
 * Adds additional product to cart based on the quantity of an added product
 */
function prefix_add_additional_product( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {
    // Get the cart
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    // Nothing, if the cart is empty
    if ( 0 == count( $cart ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Enter the free product ID
    $additional_product_id = 96;

    // Don't add accessory when adding the same accessory
    $added_product_id = 0 < $variation_id ? $variation_id : $product_id;
    if ( $added_product_id == $additional_product_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // You can add checks for specific product ID or some other requirements here

    $additional_product_quantity = (int) ( $quantity / 5 );

    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $additional_product_id, $additional_product_quantity );
}
```

https://gist.github.com/vanbo/f42cfa8bdf593013f77dda605a9876bb

The code should add the `$additional_product_id` to cart with a quantity that matches the amount of times the added product to cart quantity can be devided by 5. 
The code is hooked to the add to cart hook.